# Getting specific output from JSON to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've had some help on here which has given me the following code:

```
const result = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.breakdown.forEach(el => {
    let key = "data";
    if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
    r[key].push(...el.counts)
  })
  return r;
}, {})
```

This gives me this output:

```
Object
data: (3) ["558045", "552531", "522877"]
__proto__: Object
```

However, the problem is my charting software is expecting the following:

```
["558045", "552531", "522877"]
```

How can I adjust my code above to actually just give me the above output instead? I tried simply removing the line:

```
let key = "data";
```

But it gives this error:

```
(index):73 Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined
    at e.breakdown.forEach.el ((index):73)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at data.report.data.reduce ((index):72)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at window.onload ((index):71)
```

Comment: so you want `["558045", "552531", "522877"]` and you get `["558045", "552531", "522877"]`...?

Comment: can't you just use `result.data`?

Comment: The log output you receive means you already have what you want. Just use it as-is. Why haven't you tried that before posting a question?

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry but it does not - it returns it with a key "data"

Comment: So just pass `result.data` along instead of `result`...? Surely you aren't asking us how to grab part of an Object...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to get the array from the attribute `data` of your object `result` not the full object :

```
result.data;
```

Instead of returning the full object `result;`.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but this then only returns one result rather than three.

Comment: Check my update

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Will mark as answered when it lets me

Comment: You're welcome, Glad I could help.